# Status of package / file design feature

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I liked the package design (later renamed to file design) feature in SonarQube to detect cycles inside my application. See this old blog post:

http://www.sonarqube.org/fight-back-design-erosion-by-breaking-cycles-with-sonar/

In the recent 6.0 version of SonarQube I can't find this anymore, there is a design plugin but that only seems to be supported until version 4.5.6. Am I overlooking something or is the file design feature just gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design-related services were [dropped in version 5.2](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553).